# How to identify cis-trans alkene isomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

Is the alkene with the representation $\ce{CH3CH=CHCH2CH3}$ a *cis-trans* isomer? If so, why? I mean, it is not like the other *cis-trans* alkenes, because all of them were symmetrical somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's talk about *geometrical isomerism* from the beginning, as I think that you don't understand it properly.

Geometrical isomerism is different spacial arrangements of atoms or groups across *any* bond under the following conditions:

1. *Restricted rotation* about a bond in the molecule.
2. Both, substituted atom or group on each *C*-atom, about which rotation is frozen or restricted should be **different**.
3. In case of *cumulenes*, odd and even number of double bond and the distance between the atom or group should be taken into consideration.

Now coming to your question, 
$\ce{CH3-CH=CH-CH2-CH3}$ can show geometrical isomerism because it follows conditions 1 and 2 given above. It can therefore form *cis* and *trans* isomers.
Which of them will be the major product depends upon the stability of the compound.

As you can see, in the given conditions there was no mentioning that the compound has to be symmetrical to form *cis-trans* isomerism. You don't have to look for symmetry, but for the above conditions.

I mentioned earlier that geometrical isomerism is a different spacial arrangement of atoms or groups across *any* bond, se let me give some examples for that:

1. Compounds containing $\ce{C=C}$, $\ce{C=N}$, $\ce{N=N}$
2. Compounds containing cyclic structures, homocyclic compounds (benzene type), heterocyclic (eg. pyridine), fused rings (eg. naphthalene), etc.
3. Compounds  containing restricted rotation about single bonds due to steric hindrance. Attached groups are so bulky, such that on rotation repulsion increases thus, decreasing the stability.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the formula could be for either:

***cis*-2-pentene**
[image: cis-2-pentene]

***trans*-2-pentene**
[image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. I can't see the difference could you please clarify more ?

Comment: The trans-2-Pentene isn't drawn quite the same way as the cis version. Redraw it with the two H atoms and you should get it. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis%E2%80%93trans_isomerism

Comment: I'll add that the $\ce{-CH3}$ group can spin about the single $\ce{C-C}$ bond, but the $\ce{C=C}$ is "locked." So the hydrogen atoms are either on the same side (cis isomer), or opposite sides (trans isomer) of the $\ce{C=C}$ bond.